# jQuery select descendants, including the parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent, descendant

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="foo" id="obj">
   I should be changed red
   <div class="bar" style="color:black;">
      I should not be changed red.
      <div class="foo">I should be changed red.</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Given a DOM element `obj` and an expression, how do I go about selecting any children and possibly `obj`?  I'm looking for something similar to "select descendants" but also including the parent, if it matches the expression.

```
var obj = $("#obj")[0];

//wrong, may include siblings of 'obj'
$(".foo", $(obj).parent()).css("color", "red");

//wrong -- excludes 'obj'
$(".foo", obj).css("color", "red");

//correct way, but it's annoying
var matches = $(".foo", obj);
if ($(obj).is(".foo")) matches = matches.add(obj);
matches.css("color", "red");
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: +1: Great question. Just hit this situation today. Have taken Andrew's answer and your comment and added a trivial jQuery `findAndSelf` extension as you suggested for everyone to use. Cheers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
$(currentDiv).contents().addBack('.foo').css('color','red');
```

I renamed the "div" to "currentDiv" for clarity.  This selects the current element and all of the elements it contains, then filters out the ones that do not have class `foo` and applies the style to the remainder, i.e., the ones that do have class `foo`.

**EDIT**  A slight optimization

```
$(currentDiv).find('.foo').addBack('.foo').css('color','red');
```

**EDIT**

This answer has been updated to incorporate newer jQuery methods.  It was originally

```
$(currentDiv).find('.foo').andSelf().filter('.foo').css('color','red');
```

which is still required for jQuery older than 1.8

Comment: Ah, thank you... the "andSelf()" is what I was missing.  Unfortunately this method is ineffecient... all of the children and found and then all are traversed to be filtered, rather than just a single pass.

Comment: This is still slightly less efficient than `addback` (JQ 1.8 onward) as this runs the `filter` a second time on the descendants even though they all already match.

Comment: `Note: This function has been deprecated and is now an alias for .addBack(), which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later`

Answer (score 9):

jQuery 1.8 introduced [.addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/), which takes a selector, in favor of .andSelf().So tvanfosson's code becomes much more efficient as

```
$(currentDiv).find(".foo").addBack(".foo").css("color", "red");
```

If you didn't have that, I think that

```
$(currentDiv).find(".foo").add(currentDiv.filter(".foo")).css("color", "red");
```

would be pretty efficient, if not very pretty.

Comment: Definitely preferred from jQuery 1.8. Have added your suggestion as a jQuery `findAndSelf` extension method below. Turned out very clean using `addBack`, *full credit to you*. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

[Andrew's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718050/andrew) answer was so useful and the most efficient of all the answers (from jQuery 1.8 onward), so I did as [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43005/sam) suggested and turned it into a trivial jQuery extension method for everyone to use:

### Extension code:

```
jQuery.fn.findAndSelf = function (selector){
    return this.find(selector).addBack(selector);
};
```

### use like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#obj').findAndSelf('.foo').css('color', 'red');
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BfEwK/

*Full credit to Andrew for suggesting `addBack()` as the best option (as at this date). Have upvoted him accordingly and suggest everyone do the same.*

Comment: How has nobody seemingly noticed this. You deserve a hug and a high-five.

Comment: @TheDembinski: Hug accepted with thanks (I don't do high 5's however) :)

Answer (score 1):

Barring a nicer solution, I've created a new function and use it instead of $:

```
var _$ = function(expr, parent){ 
   return $(parent).is(expr) ? $(expr, parent).add(parent) : $(expr, parent); 
}
```

Comment: I think I'll just use this and extend jQuery to make it "findAndSelf()" or something like that.

Comment: Have applied your `findAndSelf` suggestion (good name) to Andrew's answer instead and posted for all to cut & paste.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way to select *all* descendant elements, including the parent element:

```
$('*', '#parent').addBack();
```

Which is the same as:

```
$('#parent').find('*').addBack();
```

```js
$('*', '#parent').addBack().css('border', '1px solid #f00');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <span>Child</span>
  <span>Another child</span>
</div>
```

Of course, you can change the universal selector to the desired element.

```
$('.foo', '#parent').addBack();
```

or

```
$('#parent').find('.foo').addBack();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken could you not just do the following?

```
$("#obj").css("color", "red").find(".foo").css("color", "red");
```

Find intended object/element apply CSS, then find all objects/elements within said object/element with said selector and then apply the CSS to is as well?

Comment: No. They only want the parent element selected *if it also has `.foo`*, but yours just includes it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('div.foo, div.foo > *').css('color','red');
```

The main idea is that you can separate different rules to match on by commas. Just like in css. As far as I know everything [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/index.htm) is supoprted by jquery and can be "ORed" by comma-separating.

Comment: This would select all .foo in the document, and all children of .foo

Comment: Right... I thought that's what you meant.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I've clarified the question.

Comment: Ok now the answer is: all divs of class foo and all their children. Satisfactory?

Comment: The answer is "all children of [some object] that match [expression] as well as [some object] if it matches [expression]"

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't this do what you want (unless I misunderstand...)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.foo").css("color", "red");
});
```

Comment: This will "work", *but only because they happened to all be `divs` in the example*. The question was how to include an initial element (if it matches) along with any descendants (that also match). What if there were more `.foo`s outside of `#obj`? They would also be included (which is not the desired behavior).