# Jquery: get ancestors (or descendants) and self

Tags: jquery, filter, ancestor, descendant

One can use `matchedset.find(selector)` / `matchedset.parents(selector)` to get the descendants/ancestors of the current matched set filtered by a selector, but that doesn't include the matched set itself (if it happens to match the selector too). Is there a better (more concise and/or faster) way to get it than

```
matchedset.find(selector).add(matchedset.filter(selector))
```

and the respective for parents() ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do this:

```
matchedset.find('*').andSelf().filter(selector);
```

For parents:

```
matchedset.parents('*').andSelf().filter(selector);
```

Comment: Which is better? `.find('*')` or `.contents()` like in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364791/jquery-select-descendants-including-the-parent

Comment: Probably a good idea to note that andSelf is now deprecated and has been replaced with addBack() which also accepts a selector.

http://api.jquery.com/addBack/

Answer (score 17):

I think your method is efficient in terms of execution time, but what you're probably asking for is syntactic sugar. For that, you could wrap it into a plugin:

```
  jQuery.fn.findAndSelf = function(selector) {
    return this.find(selector).add(this.filter(selector))
  }
```

Then use it like this:

```
$('.whatever').findAndSelf('.awesome')
```

If you wanted to get fancy you could create a plugin that works not only for 'find' but for 'parents' and 'children' and other selector-based plugins:

```
  jQuery.fn.withSelf = function(plugin, selector) {
    return this[plugin](selector).add(this.filter(selector))
  }
```

Then you'd supply as the first argument the traversal plugin you want to call:

```
$('.whatever').withSelf('find', '.awesome')
$('.whatever').withSelf('parents', '.awesome')
```

Just for kicks, another fun plugin that lets you call an arbitrary number of traversal plugins all at once:

```
  jQuery.fn.traverse = function(plugins, selector) {
    var set = new jQuery();
    $.each(plugins, function(i, val) {
      set.add(this[val](selector));
    }
    return set
  }
```

You could invoke this one with any combination of selector-based plugins, as follows:

```
$('.whatever').traverse(['find','filter'], '.awesome')
$('.whatever').traverse(['parents','find'], '.awesome')
$('.whatever').traverse(['parents', 'filter'], '.awesome')
```

Answer (score 2):

While Jeoff's solution is nice, sometimes it's nice to be able to iterate all the elements, including itself without a selector. This add-on is a bit more flexible:

```
$.fn.all = function(selector) {
    if(selector===window.undefined) return this.find('*').andSelf();
    return this.filter(selector).add(this.find(selector));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the "andSelf()" function.

Comment: andSelf() doesn't take a selector

Answer (score 0):

For parents you have `closest(selector)`